# Formatting styled-components in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide, styled-components

I'm using PhpStorm.
I'm using [Styled and Components & Styled JSX plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9997-styled-components--styled-jsx)  for support for styled components. It is very useful because it provides cool features like code completion and suggestions. However, it could be really useful if I could format code that I'm writing. Does anyone know how can I format styled-components code in PhpStorm?

In the picture you can see that the code is not formatted and unless I formatted it myself it will stay as it is.
Thanks in advance :)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Auto-formatting doesn't work as expected in injected CSS with interpolations, please follow [WEB-28540](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-28540) for updates. See https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-32048#focus=streamItem-27-3300923.0-0 for details

Related [Styled and Components & Styled JSX](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9997-styled-components--styled-jsx) plugin plugin issue: https://github.com/styled-components/webstorm-styled-components/issues/60